# How to distribute the filter result? (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I want to retrieve 5 clothes for each parent_types ("top", "bottom", "shoes")

```
user.clothes_set.filter(type="top")[:5]
user.clothes_set.filter(type="bottom")[:5]
user.clothes_set.filter(type="shoes")[:5]
```

I want to do it more efficient way. (three filters are nasty!)

```
top, bottom, shoes = user.clothes_set.filter(~~~) <- retrieve `5 items each`
```

here is expected cloth models

```
class Clothes(models.Model):
    id
    type =      # top, bottom and shoes 
    owner = ForeignField  # some one who post
```

Should I re-design the model? should I exclude the 'type' field to class? or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
user.clothes_set.filter(type__in=['top', 'bottom', 'shoes'])[:5]
```

*Update*: As following the comment;

```
offset = lambda t: user.clothes_set.filter(type=t)[:5]
top, bottom, shoes = offset('top'), offset('bottom'), offset('shoes')
```

Comment: He wants 5 of each type not 5 in total.

Comment: @SancaKembang this is not in any way more efficient than John solution performance wise it is same

Comment: You can rewrite my model too.. You may add Type as another class?? um

Comment: As setting `type` as a choice, your solution may work. But I just thought maybe if set `type` as ManyToMany, I might have better performance especially on this case. I'm just guessing :P

Comment: I do not know yet, but you can using this [chrome extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/django-debug-panel/nbiajhhibgfgkjegbnflpdccejocmbbn/related?hl=en) to compare the performances also [this article](http://bookofstranger.com/optimizing-django-orm-queries-for-best-performance/)...